How to properly configure my nginx.conf for an Azure app service site? Having 404 errors
I'm a server newbie and am struggling to fix 404 errors on my Azure app service site (Linux, Nginx, MySQL, PHP).
Using the default configuration, I was having issues with any file paths causing 404's (images, css, js, etc.). Originally it was using relative paths, but I had no luck with any other variations). I decided to start monkeying around with the nginx config and only made things worse by accidentally overwriting my original default config. Now I have the same issues, but also can't access any pages other than index. I have a startup command that copies the custom nginx.conf file to the usual location (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default).
Can anyone help sort out my config? Or at least provide the original default config that I lost? Here is my current nginx.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    root /home/site/wwwroot/themes/mywebsite.com;

    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.+)) {
        return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;  # Ensure the PHP-FPM is running on this address and port
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /css/ {
        alias /home/site/wwwroot/themes/mywebsite.com/css/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /js/ {
        alias /home/site/wwwroot/themes/mywebsite.com/js/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /images/ {
        alias /home/site/wwwroot/themes/mywebsite.com/images/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~* \.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|css|js|jpg|gif|png|pdf|swf|svg|svgz|ico|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|webp)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        expires 1M;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, immutable";
    }

    error_log /home/LogFiles/nginx/error.log debug;
    access_log /home/LogFiles/nginx/access.log combined;
}


Can you share your github repo ?

Can you provide the log stream of your Azure app service?

check this doc once.

The only thing I get in the log stream when loading the homepage is: [ERROR]  127.0.0.1 -  10/Jun/2024:13:16:13 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200. It says error, but then says 200, so I don't know what that means. That article just details the default way to make an nginx file be used by the app.
